# "Analytics" vs "Stats"

Tags: dashboard, wording

[image]

I'm designing a dashboard for an e-commerce site. Inside it, there's a page where the store owner can see some data and charts about their sales, revenue, number of customers, etc.

What's the best word for its link label? "Analytics" or "Stats" or maybe another word?

Comment: Statistics is passively saying "Here you can find data". Analytics is more actively saying "Here you can draw conclusions from data". The suggested "Report" can imply that the conclusions are already drawn with some selected data as foundations. It is not possible to advice one without more contextual background.

Answer (score 2):

**Analytics** can easily be related to *Google Analytics*, which can lead to confusing the type of information offered.

**Statistics** is a good option, although I don't see it particularly successful since it almost always implies a numerical comparison.

I think when you refer to sales, revenue, number of customers, etc, you are talking about internal information of the store, so I would prefer a more specific term:

- Store info
- Info
- Store data
- Reports

Comment: I think "reports" is a good alternative. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Analytics" is formal but understood as a term for showing performance data.

"Stats" is informal/playful but might not immediately infer performance.

Is your app formal in nature, or informal? If you're not sure, do an A/B test and see which gets more clicks.